Pass filename dynamically in dataflow synapse pipeline - source as excel
I am trying to pass filename as parameter to dataflow in synapse pipeline but facing issues.
I am setting a variable and passing that to dataflow as below.

Also created a parameter inside the dataflow

Also inside source

Inside connection given filepath as

Wildcard path under source as

When I try to import projection getting error. No idea about this, appreciate your help in resolving this. I suspect may be I am doing something wrong in passing parameters?

This is the file which I am trying to access in source


If you want to pass filename as parameter to dataflow follow below procedure:
Create dataset string parameter fileName for dataset as shown below:

Create pipeline string parameter fileName with value as shown below:

Provide above parameter as set variable value @pipeline().parameters.fileName as shown below:

In data flow provide the variable fileName which is created in set variable activity to the data flow @variables('fileName') as shown below:

Then you will be able to pass file name successfully without any error.
Note: No need to create parameters in data flow to pass file name while parameter created in dataset.

Thanks @bhavani. But your images are not visible. Can you please edit your images again?

Images are visible, please refresh the page once or check your network once.

My network is all good but not sure why I am not able to see the images

Provide the screenshot of answer

I don't think I can share the screenshot in comment.


https://i.imgur.com/EBQR0nu.png
https://i.imgur.com/BztNabr.png
https://i.imgur.com/aufbDbj.png
https://i.imgur.com/OOniRQs.png
check the links order wise.


Let us continue this discussion in chat.
